# bind jquery event on event

Tags: events, jquery

i'm listening to a click event. When triggered, I need to bind a different event (for other element) but it keeps triggering both on the first event.

My code:

```
$(".element1").on("click", function(){  
    console.log("triggered element1");  
    $(".element2").on("click", function(){  
        console.log("triggered element2");  
    })  
});
```

Comment: What are you expecting? What are you getting?

Comment: Eww, this will register multiple click events on `.element2`! Watch out!

Comment: What's the relationship between `element1` and `element2`? Show some HTML.

Comment: It does not trigger both on clicking the first element, unless it's the same element with two classes, but you will bind a new function to the second element every time you click the first element etc.

Comment: This will append a click handler to `element2` each time `element1` is clicked. Perhaps you should avoid double binding?

Comment: To prevent the multiple bindings you could do `$(".element2").unbind("click").on("click", ...`

Comment: @monxas Does your html look anything like this? http://jsfiddle.net/6dXEs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A separate copy of the event handler for `.element2` will get bound every time `.element1` is clicked. If you want to prevent that, remember in a variable whether you have already bound the handler.

```
var e2bound = false;
$(".element1").on("click", function(){  
    console.log("triggered element1");  
    if(!e2bound){
        $(".element2").on("click", function(){  
            console.log("triggered element2");  
        })
        e2bound=true;
    }
});
```

An alternative solution would be to unbind the first handler when it runs:

```
$(".element1").on("click", function e1handler(){  
    console.log("triggered element1");  
    $(this).off("click", e1handler);
    $(".element2").on("click", function(){  
        console.log("triggered element2");  
    })  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.off()` to remove the event and use `e.stopPropgation()`

```
$(".element1").on("click", function(){  
    console.log("triggered element1");  
    $(".element2").off('click').on("click", function(e){  
        e.stopPropagation();
        console.log("triggered element2");  
    })  
});
```

Frequent binding and unbinding is a bad practice..  need to avoid it if possible.. 
It will be easier if you can show the HTML structure..

Comment: It is better to bind conditionally, not discard an existing handler if exists. Discarding _all_ handlers is certainly not a good idea